# What is the difference between these two configurations to run Django?

Tags: python, django, apache, fastcgi, django-wsgi

I have these two configurations. I would like to know what's the difference and which one is better and faster?

First configuration:

```
#!/home/user/bin/python
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/user/projects/")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
WSGIServer(WSGIHandler()).run()
```

Second configuration:

```
#!/home/user/bin/python
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/user/projects/")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Thanks!

**Update:**

[I did a quick test with python cProfile lib](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aq0kIyLkJbOAdEl1R1l2UGtRamt0d2tvZ1dsRGJKWnc&hl=es).

Comment: You're not going to get an answer like, "FastCGI is always faster than wsgi," if that's what you're looking for. The real answer is, "It depends on your software and hardware configuration." Try running both, and benchmarking them with something like JMeter. http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django uses WSGI natively, so running it through FastCGI adds another layer for the HTTP messages to travel through. Having said that, if you have the choice between a quick FastCGI container or a slow WSGI container, you may be better off living with the extra layer.

Comment: then, is better to use the first configuration even though WSGI container is slower?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know anything about the container.

Comment: WSGI is an API. You don't have much choice but to have WSGI sit on some sort of adapter. For FASTCGI/SCGI/AJP you can use flup. For mod_wsgi it interfaces WSGI to Apache stack. Then you have gunicorn which interfaces WSGI direct into a Python HTTP server. This layer is usually never the bottleneck anyway, more important to analyse performance of the application and database.